# how to check the times if it is greater or less than

Tags: php

I am working on my PHP script to scrapping the data from the website. On the day 1 to day 7, if the flag is 0 I want to check on the times to see if the time is less than `12:00 AM` then I want to use `flag = 1`

Example: The time `10:00 PM` and `11:59 PM` which is less than `12:00 AM` so i can use `flag = 1`

Here is the code:

```
if($day>=0 && $day <= 7)
{
   $flag=0;

   if($day >= 1)
   {
      if ($flag == 0)
      {
         print_r($show_times);
      }
   }
}
```

Here is the results:

```
Array ( [0] => 22:00 [1] => 03:00 [2] => 04:00 [3] => 06:00 [4] => 08:00 [5] => 10:00 [6] 
=> 11:00 [7] => 12:00 [8] => 13:00 [9] => 13:55 [10] => 14:25 [11] => 14:55 [12] 
=> 16:55 [13] => 18:10 [14] => 18:40 [15] => 19:00 [16] => 19:30 [17] => 20:00 [18] => 20:55 [19] 
=> 21:55 [20] => 23:10 [21] => 00:40 [22] => 01:00 [23] => 01:30 [24] => 02:00 ) 10:00 PM KSW 39
```

Here is the full code:

```
<?php
function get_shows($day,$channel_id, DateTime $dt, $today = false) 
{

   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
      CURLOPT_USERAGENT => '',
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
      CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 30,
      CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
      CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 5,
      CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false
   ));

   $date = $dt->format('Y-m-d');
   $tz = $dt->getTimezone();

   $now = new DateTime('now', $tz);
   $today = $now->format('Y-m-d');
   $shows = array();
   $url = 'https://www.example.com/scrip.php?date=' . $date;
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   $body = curl_exec($ch); //get the page contents

   $channel_row = $row_channels[0][0]; // Woksepp: 0 = First row.

    $pattern23 = "/<a class=\"prog\" href=\"(.*?)\">.*?<span class=\"time\">(.*?)<\/span>.*?<span class=\"title\" href=\"\#\">(.*?)<\/span>.*?<span class=\"desc\">(.*?)<\/span>/s";
    preg_match_all($pattern23, $channel_row, $d);
    $show_times = $d[2];

    //test this
    if($day>=0 && $day <= 7)
    {
        $flag=0;

        if($day >= 1)
        {
           if ($flag == 0)
           {
              print_r($show_times);
           }
        }
    }
}
```

What I'm expecting to do is I want to check if the time show `22:00` or whatever it is that comes before the middle night time `00:00`, then I want to set the flag to 1 so I can skip the time in the array.

Can you please show me an example how I can check the time between `22:00` and `23:59` to see if the time is less than `00:00` so I can use `flag = 1` under the if statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
if($day >= 1)
{
    foreach($show_times as $show_time)
    {
        if(strtotime($show_time) < strtotime('12:00'))
         {
             $flag=1;
         }
    }
}
```

This will check if the time is less than `noon` and set the `$flag` to `1`

Comment: thank you very much for this as i can see it is work great, but I want to use `$day >= 1` because on the code you use it will use between day 0 to day 7 so can you please change your code?

Comment: IF the solution was helpful please be sure to accept it.